# Where does Paypal's ipn_email come from?

Tags: php, paypal

In my PHP code for handling the IPN, everything works fine, except for one line:

```
$email = $_GET['ipn_email'];
```

This was in the example code they offer in order to get you started. I assumed it would retrieve the email address that was associated with the administrator of the Paypal account doing the billing.

However, it seems to never get set. If I use the code above, my IPN script fails. The only way my IPN script works is if I simply set `$email` to some arbitrary email address of my choosing.

Is is okay for me to just set my own email address? Should I be getting an `ipn_email` value from `GET` data? What is the value of `ipn_email` supposed to be?

Comment: I haven't worked with PaxPal's APIs, but having completed transactions as a user, I know that I can specify if I wish to share my email with the person/company receiving my money. So this might be why you are not getting the email. Also; have you tried examining the whole $_POST and $_GET variables (print_r()) to see what you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_GET[]` variables are retrieved from the querystring within the url. Therefore to send set the one your asking the user must request

```
host/page.html?ipn_email=an_email_address
```

If your not sending that format to the server the variable will never be set.

Not sure if you used this tutorial but it explains one reason for using it

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNImplementation